# is there any evidence that there are ~75 extra elements on the periodic table?

Tags: periodic-table

there are 118 currently existing elements on the periodic table, and recently I've found like 77 elements that quote on quote "may exist" on our periodic table. Is this true?

Comment: Search the internet and you  will get the answer

Comment: Questions are downvoted, not users - but I know that they can be off-putting either way. Do be sure to use the help center, and the search. As pointed out, there are resources out there that could give you some idea, eg : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_periodic_table

Comment: oh okay, I thought people were just downvoting because they could.

Comment: The answer is nobody knows.  See the referenced question in the "duplicate question" block for some ideas.

Comment: okie dokie, I'll go check it out :)

Comment: Also you should probably cool down a bit, and check [help].